# Jquery, Navigation bar and toggle() issues

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, navigation, toggle

ok so i have a navigation bar that contains a list of links being displayed using the inline-block style. I used a media query so that when i resize the screen to a smaller size, if the list doesnt fit on the bar anymore, it transforms into a dropdown menu, with a button that helps toggle the visibility of the dropdown menu on and off. The button works using this simple jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav-menu").click(function(){
        $("#nav-links").slideToggle("down");
    });
});
```

(#nav-menu is the id of the button, while #nav-links is the id of the list)

My problem is that when I click the menu button and it hides the dropdown menu, and right after that i resize the browser screen to it's normal width, it stays hidden. How do I force  the list of links to stay visible when i resize it back to normal width, regardless of whether I left the dropdown menu on or off? Please excuse me if there was a forum elsewhere and I didn't check, I don't have much time left before my website needs to be finished.

for a visual example, check out impactbnd.com, look at the navigation bar on top, then resize the browser and look at the dropdown menu to give you an idea of what im trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use resize() to show() your dropdown menu when a certain width is exceeded.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if($( window ).width() >= XXX){
        $("#nav-links:hidden").show();
    }
    else{
        $("#nav-links:visible").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: neat! I knew it had to look something like this, but i was trying to figure out the syntax (sorry haven't used jquery much). Now the only minor issue is that when i resize back down, the dropdown menu is automatically open before I even press the menu button. I tried this similar code for when i resize below the specified width, but no luck...

Comment: I tried it out but not much help. I thought about doing this too but it kept the container hidden regardless of window size (don't know why it would act up like that but it did). Anyways, because of time, I decided to make a second list and altered the visibility of it using media queries. Thanks for the help though.